# How do i fix this vertical scrollbar in my site?

Tags: css, overflow, display

I have a container that adds a vertical scrollbar and i don't know how to fix it

```
.albums {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I tried to align vertically the items inside of the container so i added min-height, but now i have a vertical scrollbar in my website.

Comment: Please provide your HTML code so others can reproduce the problem, or better - create a minimal reproducible example.
If you have a live example, please share a link.
Overflow problems tend to be one of the trickest to fix, as they can be caused by a seemingly unrelated element on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

the contents of your albums object are overflowing it's area. By setting overflow to auto, a scrollbar is shown, when the content gets bigger in **any** direction.

I think you want to use this:

```css
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Or set overflow property to hidden, if you don't want to have any scrollbars at all. More information on overflow property here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.php

But be aware of the possibility of invisible content flowing outside of albums box.